# redirect 301 send me to the absolute path of the website

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My problem is the following:

Here is my website put into the www root of wamp

Here my directives for the redirect 301

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^mission/?$ mission.php [R=301]
RewriteRule ^contatti/?$ contatti.php [R=301]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?slug=$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^page/single/([^/]+)/?$ single.php?titolo=$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin/login.php [R=301]
```

If i type the redirected url, the original url appears

i.e.

type

```
http://root/page/recensioni
```

appears

```
http://root/page.php?slug=recensioni
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Show example: type/appears/wanted result

Comment: I want to override the url to have for example root/page/pagename/ when i type that url it recognizes me that that url is correct but it send me to the absolute url, root/page.php?pagename=pagename. Why?

Comment: What do you want it to do? If you want it so that /mission actually loads the mission.php etc? You need to remove the 301 so it is done "under the hood". 301s are meant for redirecting users and browsers, not rewriting a URL to another.

Comment: That’s exactly what a 301 redirect is _supposed_ to do – tell the client that the address of a resource has changed, and that he should make a _new_ request with the new address given. If you don’t want that – then _don’t_ do a 301 redirect, d’oh!

Comment: Jonathon, i want that mission.php etc loads /mission, it's the opposite process. CBroe, i've read that if you use the 301 directive you, the client will see the url changed, no?

Comment: The full result is this http://localhost/C:/wamp/www/single.php?titolo=tante-prove-di-tante-prove but C:/wamp/www/ is localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (client don't see changes in url, but loading correct file for processing request)

> ```
> RewriteEngine On  
> RewriteRule ^mission/?$ mission.php [L]
> RewriteRule ^contatti/?$ contatti.php [L]
> RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?slug=$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^page/single/([^/]+)/?$ single.php?titolo=$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin/login.php [L]
> ```

Comment: ok so when i'm in local i can't see the rewrite process? just to understand

Comment: Yes, in browser you will not see the rewrite process, but in backend all working correctly